# RabbitMQ c# client asynchrony support

Tags: c#, asynchronous, rabbitmq

I have this piece of code and i use [rabbitmq client](http://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet.html). i m curious if this is asynchronous or synchronous? if synchronous, how can i make it async ?

```
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.HostName = "localhost";
        using (IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (IModel channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare("hello", false, false, false, null);
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                string message = "Hello World!";
                byte[] body = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

                channel.BasicPublish("", "hello", null, body);

            }

        }
```

Comment: Your question is a little confusing.  You are publishing to a queue the same message 1000 times.  What is it supposed to be synchronized with.  If it is with who ever is reading the queue then it is async.  ie the consumer does not need to read before the next one is published

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See chapter 2.9 of [official C# client guide](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v3.0.0/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-3.0.0-user-guide.pdf):

> Application callback handlers must not invoke blocking AMQP operations (such as 
>   IModel.QueueDeclare, IModel.BasicCancel or IModel.BasicPublish). If they do, the channel will deadlock

BasicPublish is imho blocking synchronous operation.

Comment: i dont find the documentation useful. the api is difficult to understand and implement, arises so many questions. Thanks for answer anyway.

Comment: U can take a look at some libraries build on top of official C# client such as EasyNetQ or MassTransit (full service bus implementation)